# Geoserver Routing with OSM data and PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openstreetmap, routing

Does Geoserver have a routing functionality for the OSM data in PostGIS?

Answer (score 5):

http://osm2postgis.sourceforge.net/

has all the components for routing with Geoserver (is in development and in Alpha)

Comment: with OSM2POSTGIS are you able to add dummy roads, modify the network, or edit existing roads?

Answer (score 5):

[OpenTripPlanner](http://opentripplanner.org) is a project developed to do multimodal routing on top of GeoServer.  It's better at transit, bike and walking than driving at the moment, but has a very powerful core routing engine.  At some point the OpenGeo team hopes to make it a community module for GeoServer, so it can be more easily incorporated.